# How to use string array to read multiple lines from files using an user defined function

Tags: c, arrays, file, user-defined-functions, fgets

I am new to the concept of using user defined functions in file handling. 
Following are the actions I would like to perform:

1. Open file
2. Use fgets() function to read a line of code and store it in the string array
3. Same way store each line as 1 string array element.

Using `fgets()` to store each line from file to string array without user defined function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* fptr1;

    char words[43][40];
    fptr1 = fopen("Skills.txt", "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("file doesnot exist\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (!feof(fptr1))
    {
        fgets(words[i], 40, fptr1);
        i++;
        count++;
    }
```

That code worked well normally, but when I tried to use a user defined function to do the job, I got an error.

Using fgets to store each line from file to string array with user defined function:

```
void getSkillsKeywords(char *WORDS[], int* COUNT, FILE* filename);
int main()
{
    FILE* fptr1;
    char *words[43];
    int count = 0;
    fptr1 = fopen("Skills.txt", "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL)
    {
        printf("file doesnot exist\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    getSkillsKeywords(words, &count, fptr1);

   for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    fclose(fptr1);
}
void getSkillsKeywords(char *WORDS[], int *COUNT, FILE* filename)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *WORDSS[43];
    while (!feof(filename))
    {
        fgets(WORDS[i], 40, filename); //exception is thrown saying Access violation while reading from file
        i++;
        *COUNT++;
    }
}
```

I have also tried to make another user defined function which is as follows:

```
   int main()
   {
       FILE* fptr1;
       int count=0;
       fptr1 = fopen("Skills.txt", "r");
       if (fptr1 == NULL)
       {
           printf("file doesnot exist\n");
           exit(1);
       }
       char** words=getSkillsKeywords(&count,fptr1);
       for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
           printf("%s\n", words[i]);
       fclose(fptr1);
    }

    char** getSkillsKeywords(int* COUNT, FILE* filename)
    {
      int i = 0, index, u;
      char** WORDS =malloc(90*sizeof(char*));
          while (!feof(filename))
          {
              printf("came in");
              fgets(WORDS[i], 40, filename); // same exception thrown
              i++;
              *COUNT++;
          }
      return WORDS;
   }
```

Since I use array of strings I was not able to use any other function than `fgets()` where I need to store each line as an element in array. Where is the mistake, and how do I fix it?

Comment: so many things wrong.  The basic problem is you are not allocating the data correctly and you are not passing it correctly

Comment: In `fgets(WORDS[i], 40, filename);` `WORDS[i]` has not been allocated. `fgets()` is going to scribble all over process process memory that it should not be scribbling on.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  You've almost got a good question there, it's just missing an [mcve] (some of your code will not compile) and the actual fault or exception message that you claim to have gotten when you run it.  I would also recommend dialing up the warning level on your compiler.

Comment: Note the difference between your working code and the failing code, is that you declare an array of characters to use for buffering in the former and an array of uninitialized pointers in the later.

Comment: I would add that `main()` is a "user defined function".  Your association of the failure with your addition of another function into the program is specious.  When you refactor code, you will often encounter these kinds of coincidences.  If you stick to programming long, you'll learn to distrust all of your own theories on the first pass, or you'll be chasing ghosts forever.

Answer (score 0):

Just fill the words array that was declared in your main function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getSkillsKeywords(char [][40], int *, FILE *);

int main() {
  FILE* fptr1;
  char words[43][40];
  int count = 0;
  fptr1 = fopen("Skills.txt", "r");

  if(fptr1 == NULL) {
    printf("file does not exist\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  getSkillsKeywords(words, &count, fptr1);
  fclose(fptr1);

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("%s", words[i]);

  return 0;
}

void getSkillsKeywords(char WORDS[][40], int *COUNT, FILE* filename) {
  // no need for the vriable `i` since you have the variable `COUNT`
  while(!feof(filename))
    fgets(WORDS[(*COUNT)++], 40, filename);
}
```

example Skills file

```
hello Hi there
Wonderful world
Grand master
How is it going
Apples and oranges
```

the output is the same note that I have removed the newline from printf function because the strings already have new line at the end.